# How to get exponential regression equation after performing linear regression on the ln transformed equation?

Tags: statistics, exponential-function, linear-transformations

The equation of an exponential function is $y = ae^{bx}$

Transforming this for linear regression: $\ln(y) = \ln(a) + bx$

Then the linear regression equation is: $\ln(y) = -369.9778 + 0.187693x$

How do I transform it back in the form of $y=ae^{bx}$??

My issue is in $\ln(a) = -369.9778$. Of how to get the $a$ value.

Thank you.

Since I cannot post photos here due to my new joining of the community: Please refer to this post for images and more in-depth analysis:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/324564/how-to-get-exponential-regression-equation-after-performing-linear-regression-on/324568#324568

Comment: I think you were meant to take the $\ln$ of both sides, not $\log$.

Comment: Oh right let me check. I used JMP to get these values. There was a log transform and log10 transform.

Comment: `Log10[Total] = -160.6793 + 0.0815141*Year` Is the new regression equation.

Comment: Your comment says Log10[Total]. You should be taking the $\ln$ of the equation, which is $\log_e$. ($\log$ base $e$)

Comment: After checking, log is actually the natural logarithm in the statistical softwares: minitab and JMP.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to approach this though? I just want to forecast the total cases (y-axis) vs. time in years (x-axis) in the next 5 years. But this is the first time i'm doing an exponential one

Answer (score 0):

If $\hat{\beta}_0 = \widehat{\ln \alpha}  = -370$, thus $\hat{\alpha} = e^{\hat{\beta}_0} = e^{-370}$.  But note that $g(x) = e^x$ is a convex transformation, hence, $\hat{\alpha}$ is a biased estimator of $\alpha$. As such, you may consider using $(\hat{\alpha}, \hat{\beta})$ as initial values for non-linear regression estimation of $y = ae^{bx}$.

Comment: An issue i'm having is that $e^{-370}$ is approximately 0 so. It makes the regression equation quite useless. If you refer to the link in the question I have some graphs that show some behaviors I observed

Comment: Well. It seem legit, as your curve is at $ y \approx 0$ until the range of $  x \approx  2000$, hence it is logical that $\alpha$ will be very small if you want to wait until $x \approx 2000$ before the curve "takes off". Probably your software rounds it to $0$, thus you get a degenerate model. I've plotted it using R and it behave like I expected.

Comment: Yes you're right. There's been a good discussion on the link on the main post regarding the issue if anyone is interested.